# How to downsync once and upsync multiple times between app (SQLite) and webservice on a daily basis?

Tags: android, web-services, android-sqlite, android-service

I want to develop an android app. I want this app to download a data(SQL rows as JSONArray) from webservice call daily at a specific time, say 8 AM. But if there is no internet by 8 AM I want the app to trigger the download(webservice call) once the internet is available. I call this process as downsync(daily once).

Once the downsync is completed I want a background process/service/thread which continuously checks the downloaded data(SQL-Lite rows in android app) if the row is changed or not.
Whenever a row is changed I want the service/process/thread to call the webservice with the modified data in the form of JSONArray provided the internet is active. If the internet is not active, once the internet is available the service should continue. Let me call this as upsync.

This upsync has to continue until all the rows are changed or until the END OF DAY.

I want this entire upsync and downsync cycle of my app to repeat daily. Webservice logics/Algorithm is not required. I want the approach from the android perspective.

I have searched many questions. This might seem duplicate. But so far no other questions here have solved all of this requirement. Any algorithm, approach or reference link would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a perfect use case for **sync adapter** you can read about it and try the example given here https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html
Creating a Sync Adapter | Android Developers

Also if you are flexible you can check out firebase database, only if you are flexible on your backend, else go with sync adapters that is meant for use  cases like yours

Comment: Can I use REST API service with Sync adapter?

Comment: Yes you can use rest, soap

Comment: Yeah I am trying out this option. Would update you thanks a lot. Would accept the answer if this works fine.

Comment: Yes this did work for me. I have completed a prototype which is working fine. Have to implement as a whole.. Thanks war_Hero

Comment: awesome glad i could help, happy coding